# best approach for Parallel threaded step in and subsequent multi step job with repetition spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a csv file or a file with delimiter '|' with 2 Million records in it.

This is my JOB that i want

```
Job
Step 1: Read records from line number 'r1' to 'r2' from the file (of 2 Million) records and transform them into a data transfer object (I want this DTO to be available in subsequent steps, please suggest a method for this too.)
Step 2: Perform some calculations on it.
Step 3: Perform some transformations on it (or rather create another DTO and use it in the subsequent steps)
Step 4: After the processing is done, I would like to commit the DTO or a set of DTO using Transaction Level DB Persistance.
Step 5(RepeatStep): Repeat this job for some other 'r3', 'r4' (record line numbers) and stop this job when there is no other r3, r4 present.
```

Now I want this job to executed in multiple threads

```
Job
--> Thread1 - Step1>Step2>Step3>Step4>....>StepN>RepeatStep
--> Thread2 - Step1>Step2>Step3>Step4>....>StepN>RepeatStep
--> Thread3 - Step1>Step2>Step3>Step4>....>StepN>RepeatStep
--> ....
--> ThreadM - Step1>Step2>Step3>Step4>....>StepN>RepeatStep
```

I want to keep '(r2 - r1) < 1000' and 'No. of Threads, M < 5', that's why i have kept a repeat step in the end because i want to process all the 2 Million Records.

And i also want these threads to keep repeating till all the records from the file are processed.

Now should there be a seperate class that calculates the values of r1, r2, r3, r4,... and provide them to this job, or batch does on it's own?

I know that this vague, but if i can get some pointers or sample codes to look into. I have some bits and pieces of codes, but i am not able to merge them.

Please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is done by chunked based reader-processor-writer combo. You can induce concurrency using an executor there.

For custom reading needs liek read r1 or r3 but skip r2 or r4 you need to implement your own reader for that.